# Не работает связь "Many to One " MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Сделал связь между таблицами в MySQL по этому урок [тыц](http://denis.in.ua/foreign-keys-in-mysql.htm), в итоге у меня получилось три таблицы: library, book_result и photosids, я создал FOREIGN KEY в таблице book_result где связал колонку book_id c айдишником в library и photo_id с айдишниоком photosids, где эта связь проявляется  ? Я создавал записи в library, photosids и book_result но никаких изменений не было.

Comment: Внешний ключ позволяет каскадно удалять (обновлять) связанные записи, запрещать удалять связанные записи, запрещает вставлять записи, если ссылка на другую запись (поле) не существует

Comment: Проблема в том, что каскадного удаления у меня нету, 3 таблицы живут собственною жизнью

Comment: Вставьте данные в book_result, где book_id нет в таблице library  и/или photo_id нет в таблице photosids

Answer (score 0):

Тип ограничения, которое поддерживает согласованность базы данных посредством отношения внешнего ключа. Как и другие виды ограничений, он может препятствовать вставке или обновлению данных, если данные станут несовместимыми; в этом случае предотвращается несоответствие между данными в нескольких таблицах. В качестве альтернативы, когда выполняется операция DML, ограничения FOREIGN KEY могут привести к удалению данных в дочерних строках, их изменению к другим значениям или установке на ноль в зависимости от параметра ON CASCADE, указанного при создании внешнего ключа.

Подробнее можно посмотреть [здесь](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/glossary.html#glos_foreign_key_constraint)

P.S.Чтоб можно было говорить что-то о конкретно вашем примере, выложите код создания своих таблиц в вопрос.